# How to convert a column of comma separated strings into lists?

Tags: python, pandas

We have a dataframe `DF_00`:

```
CODE FACTORS
00 000049668192,000049083092,000049239900,000049304492,000049200300,000049066092
03 000049089310
08 000049239900,000049196700,000049387200
33 000049150097,000049015792
40 000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049768051
42 000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049768051
60 000049347300
61 000049089310
```

We need to obtain `DF_01`:

```
CODE FACTORS
00 ['000049668192','000049083092','000049239900','000049304492','000049200300','000049066092']
03 ['000049089310']
08 ['000049239900','000049196700','000049387200']
33 ['000049150097','000049015792']
40 ['000049768051','000049768051','000049768051','000049768051']
42 ['000049768051','000049768051','000049768051','000049768051']
60 ['000049347300']
61 ['000049089310']
```

What we need to do?

Comment: ``df.FACTORS.str.split(',')``

Comment: Hi, thank by your answer.  The solution is not valid. Array elements are not enclosed in quotes, as in the output example (df_2) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
df['FACTORS'] = df['FACTORS'].str.split(',').astype(str)
print(df)

   CODE                                            FACTORS
0     0  ['000049668192', '000049083092', '000049239900...
1     3                                   ['000049089310']
2     8   ['000049239900', '000049196700', '000049387200']
3    33                   ['000049150097', '000049015792']
4    40  ['000049768051', '000049768051', '000049768051...
5    42  ['000049768051', '000049768051', '000049768051...
6    60                                   ['000049347300']
7    61                                   ['000049089310']
```

Comment: Hi, thank by your answer.  The solution is not valid. Array elements are not enclosed in quotes, as in the output example (df_2) above.

Comment: Do you want a list of strings or do you want it to print that way? This is already a list of strings. Not sure what you want here?

Comment: Check edited answer if you want to explicitly convert it to string.